Typescript object mapping type fix
I have these types:
type AUnion = 'A'|'AA'|'AAA'
type BUnion = 'B'|'Number'

type ValueType = {
'A': string;
'AA': string;
'AAA': string;
} | {
'B': string;
'Number': number;
}

I have a function receiveing two params, one is the value and another is the message:
const myFn = (value: ValueType, message: AUnion | BUnion) {
  const mappingResult = value[message]
  return mappingResult 
}

When I do this mapping, the TS shows error that 'A' does not exist on type ValueType, how should I correct this type?
The value initially from another mapping, like
const mapping = {
    m1: "abc",
    m2: "edf",
    aUnion: {
        A: "aUnionA",
        AA: "aUnionAA",
        AAA: "aUnionAAA",
    },
    bUnion: {
        B: "bUnionB",
        Number: 123,
    },
}

type MappingKey = "m1" | "m2" | "aUnion" | "bUnion"

key is the key of mapping
and
const value = mapping[key]

i have another function return the string case
if (typeof value === 'string') return mapping[key]

this is why I have a union type left

Why this happens is because the type of ValueType is a union of two types. Now there is a possibility that message is of type AUnion and ValueType if of type {
'B': string;
'Number': number;
}

This can be fixed using generics. Does this help : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggqgOwJYHsFQLxQOQ2wH1z0JlOwChRIoAhRVdLbGg7AOQFcBbAIwgCcKlcNBgBnTFADe5XNgBcUMcH5IEAcwDcssouWqN2onj0q1W8gF9tw6jQlYZzBUrOHZnXgJcJufftrW5MFU0ABqAIYANhwQACoikuJQ+LRiNqGwNEn0aCm0uQg2AMZoylBcIABijFAAPACyUBAAHsAQCAAmEpEx8SIAfAAUAG7RsYoNADQVEGJiEeoQigDWECAoAGZQDQCUmAPS5FBQpQjlXBFgYOYASnMcUcCSY30A2lxzC0sAusdQ-AgwA4-HQl2udweTygVmClRqdXEwycJhw82wUx0qOw8zEGKx2LE3U6+MsUzkuzh1QQiLEyJ0LhxeMxREZuPxxjZxNJ5JYuyAA If yes I can write up an answer

@TusharShahi this is literally my answer that you posted

This is not your answer because I have a single generic, makes it simpler. I did not go through your answer, sorry. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggqgOwJYHsFQLxQOQ2wH1z0JlOwChRIoAhRVdLbGg7AOQFcBbAIwgCcKlcNBgBnTFADe5XNgBcUMcH5IEAcwDcssouWqN2onj0q1W8gF9tw6jQlYZzBUrOHZnXgJcJufftrW5MFU0ABqAIYANhwQACoikuJQ+LRiNqGwNEn0aCm0uQg2AMZoylBcIABijFAAPACyUBAAHsAQCAAmEpEx8SIAfAAUAG7RsYoNADQVEGJiEeoQigDWECAoAGZQDQCUmAPS5FBQpQjlXBFgYOYASnMcUcCSY30A2lxzC0sAusdQ-AgwA4-HQl2udweTygVmClRqdXEwycJhw82wUx0qOw8zEGKx2LE3U6+MsUzkuzh1QQiLEyJ0LhxeMxREZuPxxjZxNJ5JYuyAA

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski's answer is correct and so is the first comment here; your code as written has the problem that myFn({ B: "", Number: 1 }, "A") is a valid call, so the compiler is right to warn you. The way to fix it is with generics.

Do you really need a union for this? I think just using the key of the type would suffice for the message.
type ValueType = {
  'A': string;
  'AA': string;
  'AAA': string;
} | {
  'B': string;
  'Number': number;
}

function myFnc<T extends ValueType, T2 extends keyof T>(value: T, message: T2): T[T2] {
  return value[message];
}

myFnc({A: "A", AA: "AA", AAA: "AAA"}, 'A'); // OK returned type string
myFnc({B: "B", Number: 1}, 'Number'); // OK returned type number

Using your own example for mapping I can get:
const mapping = {
  m1: "abc",
  m2: "edf",
  aUnion: {
    A: "aUnionA",
    AA: "aUnionAA",
    AAA: "aUnionAAA",
  },
  bUnion: {
    B: "bUnionB",
    Number: 123,
  },
} as const;

type ValueType = typeof mapping[keyof typeof mapping];

function myFnc<T extends ValueType, T2 extends keyof T>(value: T, message: T2): T[T2] {
  return value[message];
}

const a = myFnc(mapping.aUnion, 'A'); // OK
const b = myFnc(mapping.bUnion, 'Number'); // OK

Or if you want to make it even more generic
function myFnc<T, T2 extends keyof T>(value: T, message: T2): T[T2] {
  return value[message];
}

myFnc(myFnc(mapping, 'aUnion'), "A"); // OK
myFnc(myFnc(mapping, 'bUnion'), "Number"); // OK


The value is from other places, initially from an object mapping, the value[message] is the second level.

Can you update your question to include why my solution wouldn't work for you? From what I can understand the issue isn't in the type but in your logic. Where you can call the function with a key that does not exist on the object.

If you have the type of the value, typescript should be able to infer the type for the message. It shouldn't matter where the original comes from.

Try This:
type AUnion = 'A' | 'AA' | 'AAA';
type BUnion = 'B' | 'Number';

type ValueType =
  | {
      'A': string;
      'AA': string;
      'AAA': string;
    }
  | {
      'B': string;
      'Number': number;
    };
const myFn = (value: ValueType, message: AUnion | BUnion) => {
  if (message in value) {
    return value[message as keyof typeof value];
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid value or message');
  }
};


Why the type of result on const result = value[message as keyof typeof value]; is never?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
